# Javascript Button, just one Time

Tags: javascript, button, canvas, xhtml

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="Starten" onclick="Draw()" />
</form>

<canvas id="Dial" height="500" width="600" style="border:1px solid #000000;" > <!-- 600,600-->
</canvas>
```

How Can I programm it, So that the button only works once.
Because, I have a problems with my Programm if the User is pressing the Button more then one time.

My Problem is, after pressing 2 times the button, every line on the canvas is going to be one colour.
I dont know how to change anything else.

Comment: I can't understand the problem. So do you want to make the button to be clicked only once? What does `after pressing 2 times the button` mean?

Answer (score 0):

I would disable the button after click.

Example:

```html
<form>
<input type="button" value="Starten" onclick="Draw(); this.disabled=true;" />
</form>

<canvas id="Dial" height="500" width="600" style="border:1px solid #000000;" > <!-- 600,600-->
</canvas>
```

Comment: Yes I found something like that as a Solution, but I am using XHTML and it doesnt work.

Comment: would you consider hiding the button after click? Since it may no longer be useful I think hiding it can be an option